# recorre array multidimencional con php

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo el siguiente array que se genera de manera dinámica de consultas a la BD.
Mi pregunta es como puedo obtener el valor numérico `Array ( [199], Array ( [531], Array ( [886]`, etc. y la posición `[availability] => DISPONIBLE` ya que realmente es lo único que necesito.

Comparto el codigo con el cual genero el array desde la BD, estoy utilizando Codeigniter 3

```
$available = array();

        foreach ($disponible["items"] as $key => $value) {
            $available[] = $this->stockAviable($value["id_producto"], $this->session->id, $value["qty"], $value["um"]);
        }

        $arrB = array('arrOrder' => $this->Dat_orders_mdl->getCompleteById($_POST['id']), 'bolPrint' => false, "availability" => $available);

        # Views
        $this->load->view('print', $arrB);
```

===========================================================================

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [status] => ok [data] => Array ( [199] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 4666.59 [price] => 2484.79 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [status] => ok [data] => Array ( [531] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 1492.22 [price] => 704.06 ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [status] => ok [data] => Array ( [886] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 1564.22 [price] => 1323.76 ) ) ) [3] => Array ( [status] => ok [data] => Array ( [900] => Array ( [availability] => NO DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 12254.93 [price] => 7501.09 ) ) ) [4] => Array ( [status] => ok [data] => Array ( [942] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 1030.92 [price] => 579.48 ) ) ) [5] => Array ( [status] => ok [data] => Array ( [1058] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 3066.54 [price] => 1542.84 ) ) ) [6] => Array ( [status] => ok [data] => Array ( [1059] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 1558.82 [price] => 784.28 ) ) ) )
```

Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
$newArray = array();
    foreach ($availability as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $indice => $datos) {
            foreach ((array) $datos as $llave => $dat) {
                if ($llave != 0) {
                    $newArray[] = $llave;
                    $newArray[] = $dat;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo cual me trae como resultado lo siguiente:

```
Array ( [0] => 199 [1] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 4666.59 [price] => 2484.79 ) [2] => 531 [3] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 1492.22 [price] => 704.06 ) [4] => 886 [5] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 1564.22 [price] => 1323.76 ) [6] => 900 [7] => Array ( [availability] => NO DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 12254.93 [price] => 7501.09 ) [8] => 942 [9] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 1030.92 [price] => 579.48 ) [10] => 1058 [11] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 3066.54 [price] => 1542.84 ) [12] => 1059 [13] => Array ( [availability] => DISPONIBLE [base_price] => 1558.82 [price] => 784.28 ) )
```

Pero no logro obtener únicamente el valor de availability y el id por así decirlo.

Comment: Se puede simplificar el array si quieres. ¿Podrías mostrar el código con el que consultaste a la BD y creaste el array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Opción 1: A partir del array generado por el usuario

Para este código `$array` contendrá el array 'Array ( [0] => 199 [1] => Array ( [availability] => ...` creado por el preguntante usando los loops:

```php
//Se extraen los ids
$all_keys = array_filter($array, 'is_numeric' ); 

//Se extraen las disponibilidades
$all_values = array_column(array_filter( $array, 'is_array'), 'availability' );

//Se junta todo
$array_deseado = array_combine($all_keys, $all_values);
```

## Opción 2: A partir del array de la base de datos.

`$array_db` es el array devuelto por la base de datos.

```php
$array_deseado = [];
foreach($array_db as $array) {
  $id = array_keys($array_db['data'])[0];
  $availability = $array_db['data'][$id]['availability'];
  $array_deseado[$id] = $availability;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, la opción 1 funciono perfectamente con lo que ya tenia realizado.